# MostPopular Trailers (for a particular region) - v3 videos API

Tags: youtube-data-api

Is there an option to get the mostPopular Trailers (specific video category) for a particular region using the latest youtube v3 api ?

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos

I can use the `chart=mostPopular` and add a `videoCategoryID`, but looking at the `videoCategory` list call, the "trailer" category has a flag - assignable set to false.

Trying to use that id(44 in this case for US region) returns an error

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=US&videoCategoryId=44&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
 "code": 400,
 "message": "The requested video chart is not supported or is not available."
```

Is there any workaround or another way to fetch the `mostPopular` trailers for a specific region using the last API's ?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is the actual answer: "The requested video chart is not supported or is not available.".

**That means, the chart "mostPopular" from US, for category 44 (Trailers) does not exists.**

Testing with different **videoCategoryId** values, for some of them is working, for some is not.

Comment: I found out that the categories listed in videoCategories.list can be used in videos.list as a videoCategoryId only if the _assignable_ argument in their snippet is **true**. I wonder why… :-(

Comment: None of them are working for me, not even ones were the `assignable` argument is `true`.